# Reload a component with different route parameters in angular4

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I am using angular2 routing. When the user re-enters the value in the search field and clicks on search, the same component needs to be reloaded but with different route parameters.

```
<button (click)="onReload()">Search</button>

onReload() {
this.router.navigate(['results',this.location]);
}
```

This is my route path for my ResultsComponent

```
{ path:'results/:location', component:ResultsComponent}
```

This function changes the URL, but it does not reinitialize the component.

In angularjs, ui-router I could achieve it like this.

```
$state.go($state.current, location, {reload: true});
```

How do I do this in angular4?

Comment: we have the same problem :(

Comment: @vistajess Do tell me if you find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

You need to perform the initialization logic within the subscription call back function within the subscription call back function of the route.params observable stream.

In your component class

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

   myLocation:string;

   constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {}

   ngOnInit() {
     this.route.params.subscribe((params:Params) => {
        this.myLocation = params['location'];
        // -- Initialization code -- 
        this.doMyCustomInitialization();
     }
   }

   private doMyCustomInitialization() {
       console.log(`Reinitializing with new location value ${this.location}`);
   }
}
```

On a different note, if you need to resolve data based on the value of 'location' you should use a resolve guard which resolves the data before the component is created. See https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard for more information regarding resolve guards and routing.

Here's a working plunkr. https://plnkr.co/edit/g2tCnJ?p=preview

Comment: I am subscribing to the params. My URL also changes to the new params. But the component doesn't reinitialize.

Comment: You need to perform the initialization logic that is based on the location value within the subscribe call back function. This way, whenever the route changes (and hence params), the initialization logic is reexecuted. For efficiency, angular does not destroy and recreate a component if the route navigated to is bound to the same component.

Comment: I tried putting the initialization logic inside the subscribe call back. It still doesn't work. Also my initialization logic is a call to a http service to which I am passing the location and obtaining the data.

Comment: In your case you need to use a resolve guard, which can use the location value. See the link i've posted in the answer above.

Comment: Guards are used to stop the routing until your asynchronous tasks are finished. In my case, the asynchronous task needs to be done after route has changed. So, I don't know how Resolve Guard can help me with this.

Comment: That is correct, that is the behavior of the guard. When the route changes (in this case a different location) the guards will resolve the data again (since it is considered as a new route). Is there a reason why you want to load the data after the route is finished (and thus component created) rather than resolving it before hand?

Comment: Previously you mentioned that placing your initialization logic in the subscribe block didn't work. How is that so? (because event if its an http call it should still work). Could you provide some code please? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151026/discussion-between-jeanpaul-a-and-cka).

Answer (score 3):

EDITED

The angular way of telling the router to do this is to use [onSameUrlNavigation](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#onSameUrlNavigation) as of angular 5.1

But I had to solve this issue in a different way([Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-re-initialize-component-when-route-params-change?file=app%2Fviews%2Fb%2Fb.component.ts)), by `subscribing` to `route events` and actually calling a `custom reInit method`.

The trick is to add all subscriptions to the same object and then unsubscribe ONLY when `ngOnDestroy` is called by angular, and doing the rest of your template vars change from the `custom destroy method`...

```
    public subscribers: any = {};

    constructor(private router: Router) {
    /** 
      * This is important: Since this screen can be accessed from two menu options 
      * we need to tell angular to reload the component when this happens.
      * It is important to filter the router events since router will emit many events,
      * therefore calling reInitComponent many times wich we do not want.
      */   
      this.subscribers._router_subscription = this.router.events.filter(evt => evt instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe((value) => { 
        this.reInitComponent();
      });
    }

    reInitComponent() {
        this.customOnDestroy();
        this.customOnInit();
    }

    customOnInit() {
        // add your subscriptions to subscribers.WHATEVERSUB here
        // put your ngOnInit code here, and remove implementation and import 
    }

    customOnDestroy() {
      // here goes all logic to re initialize || modify the component vars  
    }

    /**
     * onDestroy will be called when router changes component, but not when changin parameters ;)
     * it is importatn to unsubscribe here
     */
     ngOnDestroy() {  
       for (let subscriberKey in this.subscribers) {
          let subscriber = this.subscribers[subscriberKey];
          if (subscriber instanceof Subscription) {
            subscriber.unsubscribe();
          }
        }
     }
```

Note that if you implement lifecylce hook ngOnInit, you should remove it and implement a custom method like in the example.

I added the `unsubscription` method because of [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16261) angular bug. Angular should actually automatically unsubscribe from router.events when destroying the component, but since this is not the case, if you do not unsubscribe manually you will end up calling http requests(for example) as many times as you entered the component.

Comment: In simple "use onSameUrlNavigation" this is the solution @CKA if this works pl. mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html

In your component you need to subscribe to the params in order to detect if they are changed.

Comment: I am subscribing to the params. My URL also changes to the new params. But the component doesn't reinitialize

Comment: Thanks for the info. I forgot to subscribe params in constructor.